# ITemplate and linkbutton click event

Tags: asp.net

In my user control I have gridview, and this grid is created programmatically, using Itemplate. In InstantiateIn methods I have this code.

```
Select Case _templateType
      Case ListItemType.Header
          Dim linkButton As New LinkButton
          linkButton.Text = "Delete"
          linkButton.CommandName = "Click"
          linkButton.CommandArgument = Me._columnID

          container.Controls.Add(linkButton)
```

I want to wired up Click event to this LinkButton, and use this event in code behind.
This is constructor of GridViewTemplate how implements ITemplate

```
Public Sub New(ByVal type As ListItemType, ByVal colname As String, Optional ByVal infoType As String = "")
    'Stores the template type.
    _templateType = type
    'Stores the column name.
    _columnName = colname

    _infoType = infoType

    _columnID = columID

  End Sub
```

and i have this call from user control:

```
bfield.ItemTemplate = New GridViewTemplate(ListItemType.Item, dt.Columns(col).ColumnName, "label")
```

where is

```
Dim bfield As TemplateField = New TemplateField()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
AddHandler linkbutton.Click, AddressOf X 'X being the method that handles the click event.
```

Comment: I have public class, how implements this ITemplate. And I can't use this. I try to use delegates but without any luck.

Answer (score 0):

```
AddHandler linkButton.Click, AddressOf linkButton_Click

Sub linkButton_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
   ' here is your click handler
End Sub
```

Comment: I have public class, how implements this ITemplate. And I can't use this. I try to use delegates but without any luck.